# Office 365 Calendar API Using EWS and OAuth 2

Tags: oauth-2.0, office365, exchangewebservices

**Please see edits at the bottom.**

I'm trying to work with the Office 365 API using EWS (not the managed API) to create/delete/update events on users' calendars.

So far, I have successfully used Basic Auth to validate that my SOAP request will work. I'm now trying to replace Basic Auth with OAuth 2. **I require the use of the Client Credentials Flow.**

Here are the steps I followed:

- Provided admin consent to the application. I launched the following URL in my browser, and provided consent using an admin account.

  ```
  https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?
      response_type=code+id_token&
      scope=openid&
      client_id=[Client ID]&
      redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/permissions&
      resource=https://outlook.office.com&
      prompt=admin_consent&
      response_mode=form_post&
      nonce=1234
  ```
- Upon granting consent, I retrieved the `id_token` from the response, and decoded it using [JWT.io](http://jwt.io). From the payload, I recorded the `tid`.
- Next I retrieved an access token by sending the following request:

  ```
  POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/[TID]/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
  cache-control: no-cache
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  Accept: */*
  Host: login.microsoftonline.com
  accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
  Connection: close

  client_id=[CLIENT ID]&
  client_secret=[CLIENT SECRET]&
  grant_type=client_credentials&
  resource=https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office.com
  ```
- Using the access token, I sent out the same request as I did using Basic Auth, except I replaced the Basic Auth header with `Authorization: Bearer [Access Token]`

I received the following error (`403 Forbidden`):
`The token contains not enough scope to make this call.`

What do I need to do to fix this error?

**Edit 1:** I added the `Use Exchange Web Services with full access to all mailboxes` application permission, and sending the SOAP message now results in an `500 Internal Server Error`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution involved the following:

1. Adding the `Use Exchange Web Services with full access to all mailboxes` application permission, since EWS doesn't allow the use of more granular permissions.
2. Adding an [ExchangeImpersonation SOAP header](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb204088(v=exchg.140).aspx) for the target mailbox.
3. Setting the [X-AnchorMailbox](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdav_101/2015/05/11/best-practices-ews-authentication-and-access-issues/) HTTP header.