# Office365 EWS API via OAUTH

Tags: curl, oauth, oauth-2.0, office365, exchangewebservices

I have implemented part to [get OAuth token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41875795/office-365-calendar-api-using-ews-and-oauth-2) for Office365 (Thanks for author for details).

***Can I load calendars from Office365 via EWS subscribing with OAuth token?
Any article with `curl` examples or correct API would be good...***

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing code. Requests for recommendations, tutorials, research, tools, libraries, code are off-topic. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, this is general reason why i'm asking it. If I would know how to get calendars via EWS with request subscribed by OAuth token, I would not ask help :)